# Magento 2 - How long does a cart session last?

Tags: magento2, cart, customer-session

My team and I are creating an email campaign to help reduce the abandon cart rate. The campaign spans over 3 days as a reminder to the customer there are items in their cart, if they come back then we'll take off 10% kind of deal. Currently we're using Foxycart and their session only lasts for about 12 hours, which doesn't help us. I'm looking into moving to Magento 2 but before we do that I wanted to get some information regarding this matter. I've seen some posts about cart sessions but they all seem to address Magento 1.9.X or under.

Also, would we be able to change the cart session time?

I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cart data is stored indefinitely unless you set up archiving of some sort.

The session itself is not. That's controlled by session and cookie lifetimes. This is no different from in Magento 1.

You'll want to make sure the cookie lifetime setting is at least 3 days, and that php's session.gc_maxlifetime setting is as well. That should do it.